# Relation simplification between hyperbolic and ordinary trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

Classically, we have the relation between cartesian and cylindrical coordinates given by:
\begin{align}
x &= r\cos(\theta),\\
y &= r\sin(\theta),
\end{align}
such that we have:
\begin{equation}
x\cos(\phi_0)+y\sin(\phi_0) = r\cos(\theta-\phi_0).
\end{equation}

The relation between cartesian and elliptic-cylindrical coordinates is given by:
\begin{align}
x &= c\cosh(u)\cos(v),\\
y &= c\sinh(u)\sin(v).
\end{align}
For simplicity, let us consider that $c=1$, such that we have:
\begin{equation}
x\cos(\phi_0)+y\sin(\phi_0) = \cosh(u)\cos(v)\cos(\phi_0) + \sinh(u)\sin(v)\sin(\phi_0)
\end{equation}

Is there a way to simplify this last equation into something similar than with cylindrical coordinates ?

The best would be to have something like : $x\cos(\phi_0)+y\sin(\phi_0) = \cosh(u+p)\cos(v+q)$. For now all I can obtain is:
\begin{align}
x\cos(\phi_0)+y\sin(\phi_0) &= \cosh(u)\frac{\cos(v-\phi_0)+\cos(v+\phi_0)}{2} \\&+ \sinh(u)\frac{\cos(v-\phi_0)-\cos(v+\phi_0)}{2}
\end{align}